# Reference parameters and recursion?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, reference, pass-by-reference

im currently going over recursion, and was wondering if reference parameters can be altered and given different value within the function, and when returned recursively to that same function does the value change. This is my problem, cause its not compiling. 
here is an example:

```
bool findnum_recur (int wanted, int & num)
{
    // if i want to increment num and call the function recursively   

    /*like this : */

    findnum_recur (wanted, num+1);

    // its giving me error, why and is there an alternative way
 }
```

Comment: `num+1` isn't an lvalue reference, Try `++num`. And be warned, `num` **is** modified.

Comment: @NathanOliver I meant `num++; findnum_recur(wanted,num);`. Nevermind, anyhow the only reason the comment is still there is because I was too lazy to delete it :P

Answer (score 4):

Not in this case. `num+1` is an rvalue, and references to non-`const` objects will not bind to rvalues.

Change the recursive call to:

```
int new_num=num+1;
findnum_recur (wanted, new_num);
```

and this will be fine. There's nothing particularly special or mysterious about references in recursive calls. A reference parameter works no differently than any other parameter, in that respect.

Alternatively, you can change the recursive function to:

```
bool findnum_recur (int wanted, const int & num)
```

and this will bind to the rvalue parameter.

Comment: thank you! wasnt familiar with rvalue and lvalue, and tbh i think thats my teacher's fault. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
findnum_recur(wanted, ++num);
```

Lvalue reference cannot be bound to rvalue that `+` returns.

Comment: @ScottHunter I deleted my comment because num++ still is an rvalue.. when my brain lets me down in embarassing ways..

Answer (score 0):

A reference parameter has to, you know, reference a variable.  `num+1` is not a variable, which is the source of the error message.

Using reference parameters in recursive function is perfectly fine; if you gave any hint of what you were trying to accomplish, one might be able to help you in doing so here.

Comment: thanks, my problem was not with the program but understanding problem just wanted to know why i had that specific error, and if it had to do with reference parameters